# background image is not displaying in react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, canvas, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I want use image background in react-chartjs-2 but its not working.
I tried in plane chartjs page and its working without any problem.

```js
const image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://www.chartjs.org/img/chartjs-logo.svg';


const plugin = {
  id: 'custom_canvas_background_image',
  beforeDraw: (chart) => {
    if (image.complete) {
      const ctx = chart.ctx;
      const {top, left, width, height} = chart.chartArea;
      const x = left + width / 2 - image.width / 2;
      const y = top + height / 2 - image.height / 2;
      ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);
    } else {
      image.onload = () => chart.draw();
    }
  }
};
```

```js
 export default function Chart() {
   return <Line options = {
      options
   }
   data = {
      data
   }
   plugins = {
    plugin
   }
   />;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plugins` must be defined as an `array` as follows:

```
plugins = {[
  plugin
]}
```

I couldn't find this information on the [react-chartjs-2](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/) page directly but taking a look at [`types.ts`](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/src/types.ts) on GitHub, I found this...

```
/**
 * The plugins array that is passed into the Chart.js chart
 * @see https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html
 * @default []
 */
plugins?: Plugin<TType>[];
```